# Cufon.refresh() issue when used with removeClass event

Tags: cufon, removeclass

I need some help.

I'm using Cufon for a custom font on a site I'm working on.
I applayed the Cufon font on the top links. So far everything is OK.

Here is my issue: As I'm making a responsive site, I want the font to change from the custom Cufon to a regular one, after the window is resized to a screen size less than 767px wide.

For this I am using the `removeClass` event:

```
<script>    
if ( $(window).width() < 767) {
$('li').removeClass('newFont');
}
</script>
```

The issue is that the Cufon font won't get replaced until the page is refreshed.

I tried with the `Cufon.refresh()` event like this:

```
<script>    
if ( $(window).width() < 767) {
$('li').removeClass('newFont');
Cufon.refresh();
}
</script>
```

But that doesn't work either, the font doesn't get replaced until I manually refresh the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.